# CloudWatch Logs role ARN must be set in account settings to enable logging

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-sam-cli

I have an API Gateway that I'm trying to deploy to dev, and I keep getting this error about CloudWatch logging. I can't find how to properly set up the permissions to deploy. Hopefully somebody has some knowledge that can help, as the documentation is very nebulous and not really helpful. I'm hoping to attach the corrects perms and policies from the template or cli.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Resource handler returned message: "CloudWatch      
Logs role ARN must be set in account settings to    
enable logging (Service: ApiGateway, Status         
Code: 400, Request ID:                              
ac7ee97a-255b-4be9-8352-66b762f87c5d)"              
(RequestToken:                                      
88b15f37-2b1c-cfa2-43d7-5ca7b8572b63,               
HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

This is my template.yaml file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  gofiber-sam-v1
  
  Sample SAM Template for gofiber-sam-v1

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60
Parameters:
  DeploymentStage:
    Type: String
    Default: dev
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - v1
    Description: Deployment Stage

Resources:
  CloudWatchLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: /aws/lambda/GoFiberApp
      RetentionInDays: 30

  GoFiberAppRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole

  GoFiberAppPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: GoFiberAppPolicy
      Roles:
        - !Ref GoFiberAppRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject
              - s3:GetObject
            Resource: "*"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - logs:CreateLogGroup
              - logs:CreateLogStream
              - logs:PutLogEvents
            Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/GoFiberApp:*
  GoFiberApp:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Metadata:
      Name: "GoFiber Sam API Handler"
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: main
      Runtime: go1.x
      Role: !GetAtt GoFiberAppRole.Arn
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        ProxyEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
  

  ApiGatewayRestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api # More info about API Resource:
    Metadata:
      Name: "AdPrompt API (is2p5yk9v3)"
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
      Auth:
        ApiKeyRequired: true
      MethodSettings:
      - HttpMethod: "*"
        LoggingLevel: INFO
        ResourcePath: "/*"
      AccessLogSetting:
        DestinationArn: !GetAtt CloudWatchLogGroup.Arn
        Format: '{"requestId":"$context.requestId","ip":"$context.identity.sourceIp","requestTime":"$context.requestTime","httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod","routeKey":"$context.routeKey","status":"$context.status","responseLength":"$context.responseLength"}'

  ApiGatewayRestApiRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - apigateway.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole

  ApiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi

  DevStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Condition: IsDev
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
      Description: Dev Stage
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
      DeploymentId: !Ref ApiGatewayDeployment
  V1Stage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Condition: IsV1
    Properties:
      StageName: v1
      Description: Prod Stage
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
      DeploymentId: !Ref ApiGatewayDeployment

Conditions:
  IsDev: !Equals [!Ref DeploymentStage, 'dev']
  IsV1: !Equals [!Ref DeploymentStage, 'v1']

Outputs:
  GoFiberAPI:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL AdPrompt API"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ApiGatewayRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${DeploymentStage}"  # Construct the API endpoint URL using the RestApiId and StageName
    Export:
      Name: "GoFiberAPI"
  ApiGatewayRestApi:
    Description: "RESTful API"
    Value: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi  # Use the intrinsic function Ref to reference the RestApiId
  ApiGatewayRestApiIamRole:
    Description: "IAM role for GoFiber API Gateway"
    Value: !GetAtt ApiGatewayRestApiRole.Arn
```

Comment: The trust policy of role "GoFiberAppRole" does not grant permissions to "apigateway.amazonaws.com" service.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` as follows (`apigateway.amazonaws.com` added):

```
  GoFiberAppRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
                - apigateway.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
```

Comment: It didn't work. This is the error I'm getting with your suggestion:

`Resource handler returned message: "CloudWatch Logs role ARN must be set in account settings to enable logging (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 2faa3196-171e-42de-8b64-733a26771936)" (RequestToken: b4e4824d-d2a1-0dcd-faed-f972759d2d1f, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest) The following resource(s) failed to create:                                                                                                                          [ApiGatewayRestApidevStage]. Rollback requested by user.`